# Rollback a write-dbadatatable with the truncate flag?

Tags: sql-server-2019, powershell, dbatools

I'm using the dbatools for our SQL Server 2019 server. When I try to import an Excel sheet, I would like to truncate the table before importing the new rows. This is possible if I add the -Truncate flag, as in:

```
Write-DbaDataTable -SQLInstance $Ins -Database $MyDB -InputObject $Excel -Table $MyTable -Schema $Sch -Truncate
```

However, I would very much like to rollback the truncate, if something else in the Write-DbaDataTable goes wrong.
Like when I get:

```
"WARNING: ... Cannot insert duplicate key"
```

Is it possible to run this a one transation, and get a complete rollback?

Comment: Can you import into an empty staging table, de-duplicate your data there, and either do a swap of your staging table for the live table or `MERGE` into the live table from your staging table?

Comment: @BenThul; yes, that was what I was trying to avoid, as it adds an extra table, and another step that can fail.

Comment: Well... you're failing now. What I've described at least gives you an intermediate step to investigate and code around. Up to you though.

Comment: @BenThul; yes, but how difficult would it be to implement a BEGIN TRAN and a COMMIT/ROLLBACK in the code?
20 years ago there was a rumor that TRUNCATE TABLE could not be RolledBack. Never true (except maybe for Oracle)

Comment: @ITThugNinja; BatchSize 1 will not work, as it is the entire batch that needs a BEGIN TRAN. I've checked the dbatools code, there are no such statements.

Comment: @ITThugNinja; I get "Write-DbaDbTableData : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UseTransaction'."
I'm using version 1.1.143